Fysetc E4 board + TMC2209 stepper driver via UART
I am trying to establish UART communication between Fysetc E4 (ESP32) board and TMC2209 driver with no luck.
Here is the github repository for Fysetc E4; https://github.com/FYSETC/FYSETC-E4
Motor UART TX1 is on pin 22, Motor UART RX1 is on pin 21. Also, there is a section that say that i need to set 2 jumer caps to set 2209 to UART mode.
I tried using multiple libraries but ended up with this one; https://github.com/janelia-arduino/TMC2209

Some microcontrollers (e.g. ESP32) allow alternative hardware serial RX and TX pins.

My code;
#include <Arduino.h>

// use SoftwareSerial library to communicate with TMC2209
//#define TMC2209_SOFTWARE_SERIAL

#include <TMC2209.h>

const int dirPin = 26;
const int stepPin = 27;
const int stepsPerRevolution = 2000;

// Instantiate TMC2209
HardwareSerial & serial_stream = Serial1;

TMC2209 stepper_driver;

const long SERIAL_BAUD_RATE = 115200;
const int32_t RUN_VELOCITY = 20000;
const int32_t STOP_VELOCITY = 0;
const int RUN_DURATION = 2000;
const int STOP_DURATION = 1000;
const uint8_t RUN_CURRENT_PERCENT = 80;

const int DELAY = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
  delay(DELAY);

  // use SoftwareSerial library to communicate with TMC2209 (rx -1 for read disable)
  //stepper_driver.setup(115200, 0, 18, 17); // baud, device address, rx, tx

  // use HardwareSerial library to communicate with TMC2209 (only ESP32 allows specifying the pins)
  stepper_driver.setup(Serial1, SERIAL_BAUD_RATE, TMC2209::SERIAL_ADDRESS_0, 21, 22); // hardware serial, baud, device address, rx, tx


  stepper_driver.setMicrostepsPerStep(1);
  stepper_driver.setRunCurrent(RUN_CURRENT_PERCENT);
  stepper_driver.enableCoolStep();
  stepper_driver.enable();
  ispis();

  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 // Set motor direction clockwise
  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);

  // Spin motor slowly
  for(int x = 0; x < stepsPerRevolution; x++)
  {
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(50);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
  delay(1000); // Wait a second
  
  // Set motor direction counterclockwise
  digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);

  // Spin motor quickly
  for(int x = 0; x < stepsPerRevolution; x++)
  {
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(50);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
  delay(1000); // Wait a second
}

void ispis()
{
  if (stepper_driver.isSetupAndCommunicating())
  {
    Serial.println("Stepper driver is setup and communicating!");
    Serial.println("Try turning driver power off to see what happens.");
  }
  else if (stepper_driver.isCommunicatingButNotSetup())
  {
    Serial.println("Stepper driver is communicating but not setup!");
    Serial.println("Running setup again...");
    stepper_driver.setup(serial_stream);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Stepper driver is not communicating!");
    Serial.println("Try turning driver power on to see what happens.");
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(DELAY);
}

Well, the motor is moving. But, I can not comminicate via UART to the TMC2209. For example, set the microstepping, or the current. I would like to do that via UART.

Just connect PDN_UART pin to TX. if you are using multiple TMC drivers then first
set addresses for TMC drivers using MS1_ADDR0 and MS1_ADDR1 pins.
for more info please read datasheet section 4 and see diagram 4.1
